# Rellenar un label desde un datatable

Tags: c#

Alguien me puede ayudar, lo que pasa es que quisiera rellenar un `label` con datos de una consulta en sql, la consulta me devuelve solo un resultado pero no logro que lo muestre en el `label` este es mi código en c#:

```
conexion.Open();
SqlCommand cmd2 = conexion.CreateCommand();
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo1", txtcod.Text);
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd2.CommandText = "select PROD_NOMBRE as Producto from dbo.CAT_PRODUCTOS where PROD_COD1 = @codigo1 ";
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
da2.Fill(dt2);
label1.Text = dt2.ToString();
conexion.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu pregunta veo un par de problemas que son de mas fácil resolución que lo que estas buscando.

Como primera medida, tu command podría ejecutar un `ExecuteScalar`, el cual devuelve directamente el valor de la primer fila y la primer columna del query resultante, con lo cual ya tendrías el valor que estas buscando.

Hacer un datatable para todo esto, es un gasto innecesario de recursos.

Sin embargo, podes traer los valores desde el datatable, accediendo a las propiedades del mismo:

`dt2.rows[0]` equivaldria a la primera fila, o sea que si haces `dt2.rows[0].columns[0]` estarias trayendo el primer valor de la primer fila.

Otra cosa que te conviene hacer, es usar un using para el objeto conexion, ya que de esa forma se liberan los recursos al terminar. Por regla general, si un objeto implementa `dispose`, usalo dentro de un using.

Comment: Muchas gracias, trataré de implementar el scalar a ver si logro hacer que funcione, disculpe la molestia soy un poco nuevo en esto :(

Comment: @p0ncho14, si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, por favor, [acéptala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.